# Modifying File GDB Feature Class Features Using QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase-api

I've installed the File GDB API using the OSGEO4W advanced installation when installing QGIS. I've had a bit of trouble with it initially and have posted a few questions with some helpful Stack members. I can now open File geodatabase feature classes in QGIS and start an edit session, but the only thing I can do is create new features using the 'Add Feature' tool. I cannot edit existing features because the 'Move Features', 'Node Tools', 'Delete Selected Features' and the 'Cut, Copy and Paste Features' Tools are all greyed out.

I've tested this using both ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.1 file geodatabases with the same result. The tools are greyed out except the 'Add Feature' tool even though the layer is selected and active.

I tested to see if I can get the tools to be active by using an ESRI Shapefile and this works which leads me to believe that the API isn't working as I think it should.....or maybe I'm just being a bonehead. Has anyone else experienced this behavior? Should I be able to modify existing features or should I only be able to create new ones?

Comment: Any chance you're using a custom coordinate system or haven't set one yet? Apparently the FileGDB SDK doesn't support "custom coordinate systems". More info here: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4578

Comment: Good news, you're not a bonehead.  Using the 1.9.0 Master and running  GDAL/OGR 1.9.2 I can add a new polygon and at the moment of creation add an attribute.  Thereafter I cannot edit anything, shape or table, even for the new feature.  Using 1.8.0 with GDAL/OGR 1.9.1 I can "read" feature classes, but no editing at all is allowed.  This is the behavior I expected at this time.  Using 1.8.0 and GDAL/OGR 1.9.2 I cannot even see or add feature classes; this I believe was a known bug although it had been labeled fixed, but I think that required manual changes to the install files.

Comment: @Paul I saw some issues about custom coordinate systems in my search. I'm using one of ESRI's out-of-the-box coordinate systems, so I'm assuming it's not 'Custom'. Who knows. Good point, though. Thanks.

Comment: @johns Thanks for that. I've been in contact with the development team. I've sent the data I am working on and they may re-open the bug if they get the same behavior I am.